# sending an array of data through postman to node

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, postman

Ok I want to send an array of data and fetch it based on its index.

```
rate = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,200];
```

[image]

when I try

```
console.log(req.body.rate); // output : [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,200]
console.log(req.body.rate[2]) // gives 0 
 // Also tried
var array = [];
array = req.body.rate;
console.log(array[2]) // same as above
```

I know I can loop and push etc. But I don't want to loop.
Can anyone help me where I am gooing wrong.

Comment: If you try `req.body.rate[3]` it gives you `,` symbol ? If yes, you need to parse `req.body.rate` because it's a string, not an array.

Comment: yup just tried.Anyway I can fix this. So , is not helping here

Comment: Please try this: `array=req.body.rate.split(',')`

Comment: what returns `req.body.rate[3]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in your case `req.body.rate` it returns a string not an array.

To obtain an `array`, use `split` method.

```
var array = [];
array = req.body.rate.split(',');
console.log(array[2])
```

Comment: well it splitted in this way [ '[10',
  '20',
  '30',
  '40',
  '50',
  '60',
  '70',
  '80',
  '90',
  '100',
  '110',
  '120',
  '200]' ]
so when I changed my array to 10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,200 its fine now

Answer (score 1):

Could you send an array of objects instead? Then you could do something like this:

```
var arr = [
    {
        "key": "value" 
    },
    {
        "key": "value1" 
    },
    {
        "key": "value2" 
    }
]

console.log(arr[1].key)
```